# Python Quickbooks: Unable to get correct authorization URL

Tags: python, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I am using Python [Quickbooks3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-quickbooks3/) library to connect with QBO. I am doing as given in example but not getting correct URL. Below is my code:

```
from quickbooks import QuickBooks

clientkey = "qyprdLl476vKE74vVDP99Rl08gn1fr"
clientsecret = "nYFWsjeVspmNBQoIaIfPDABblYYBeX8SAhpDTMXY"

client = QuickBooks(
    sandbox=True,
    consumer_key=clientkey,
    consumer_secret=clientsecret,
    callback_url='http://localhost/qbo_token.php'
)

authorize_url = client.get_authorize_url()
request_token = client.request_token
request_token_secret = client.request_token_secret

print(authorize_url,request_token,request_token_secret)
```

It prints:

```
('https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin?oauth_token=true', u'true', u'Ua3e7ZzPdac98RAZ1PSQJ6fjOEb9COiFDbdEQUdW')
```

Also, I want to skip browser based authorization as it would only be me using app. How can I do that?

Comment: You should probably keep the `clientkey` and `clientsecret` a secret. Bad idea exposing it to everyone. Probably reset those keys.

Comment: it's fake, no worries.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of questions here. For starters:

```
callback_url='http://localhost/qbo_token.php'
```

If you're using Python, why are you pointing to `.php` script for OAuth?

Are you sure you're using your `sandbox` OAuth consumer key and secret?

> Also, I want to skip browser based authorization as it would only be
>   me using app. How can I do that?

You can't skip it.